# How to fix '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at' error in Devise mail confirmation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, devise-confirmable

I'm a beginner programmer Rails. I'll start with a problem: I'm using Devise to work with users, and I tried to enable mail confirmation. It doesn't work, unfortunately. If possible, please help!
My error:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

My config/environments/develorment.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "xyz@gmail.com",
  password: "xyz", 
  domain: "gmail.com",
  openssl_verify_mode: "none",
}
```

My config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = "xxx@gmail.com"

config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
```

My server starts with configurations:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.5 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.2.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 6074
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And Errors in files (or what is it called):

```
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:1088:in `check_auth_response'
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:845:in `auth_plain'
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:837:in `public_send'
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:837:in `authenticate'
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:670:in `do_start'
net-smtp (0.3.3) lib/net/smtp.rb:611:in `start'
mail (2.8.1) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:109:in `start_smtp_session'
mail (2.8.1) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:100:in `deliver!'
mail (2.8.1) lib/mail/message.rb:2145:in `do_delivery'
mail (2.8.1) lib/mail/message.rb:253:in `block in deliver'
actionmailer (7.0.5) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:588:in `block in deliver_mail'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionmailer (7.0.5) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:586:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.8.1) lib/mail/message.rb:253:in `deliver'
actionmailer (7.0.5) lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:119:in `block in deliver_now'
actionmailer (7.0.5) lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:17:in `handle_exceptions'
actionmailer (7.0.5) lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:118:in `deliver_now'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:204:in `send_devise_notification'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:121:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:136:in `block in resend_confirmation_instructions'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:239:in `pending_any_confirmation'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:135:in `resend_confirmation_instructions'
devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:321:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
devise (4.9.2) app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:11:in `create'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.0.5) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.0.5) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
actionview (7.0.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'
activerecord (7.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (7.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:61:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:26:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:60:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
railties (7.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The message is shown in the terminal.
And yes, I know it's important, e-mail exists, and the data is taken from it.

I tried many options, including the part of the code that I ended up with. Nothing helps.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please upvote by way of thanks and tick by way of accepting my answer if I have solved your question for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to ActionMailer configuration rather than Devise.
From the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) authentication should be set to one of the following
`:plain`, `:login` or `:cram_md5`

The following is an excerpt taken from the relevant section in the documentation linked to above and is the explanation of the available options and what they do, so it all depends on your mail server as to which you wish to use however you can see that SSL is not amongst the available options

> :authentication - If your mail server requires authentication, you
> need to specify the authentication type here. This is a symbol and one
> of :plain (will send the password in the clear), :login (will send
> password Base64 encoded) or :cram_md5 (combines a Challenge/Response
> mechanism to exchange information and a cryptographic Message Digest 5
> algorithm to hash important information)

As requested, a typical gmail configuration would be to use SMTP like so

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  open_timeout:         5,
  read_timeout:         5 }
```

Taken from the [rails action mailer documentation section 5.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Make sure to replace username x's and password x's with your credentials and NEVER post your credentials anywhere public, I suggest you amend your password on your google account immediately, I have edited your question to hide your password but it is still available to view by those with the correct privileges

Comment: Thanks for your input, I sincerely appreciate it! But unfortunately your settings didn't fix the error...
P.S.: I hid my data, thanks for the tip! 
Could this be related to the Rails version? I have to give you complete information.

Comment: @NoTProgger what error are you having now?, that config works for me, could it be a port config issue on your server? Did you update the domain to use smtp rather than mail?

Comment: @NoTProgger Please see my updated answer with a link to the ActionMailer basics documention that should give you everything you need to know

Comment: My respect for you! I figured it out thanks to you! Wish you all the best! Thank you!

Comment: @NoTProgger, Glad you got it sorted, please accept my answer